# Windows Azure - Remote Name cannot be resolved from inside VM

Tags: azure, dns

My app connects to a webservice but to get data. The URL is not returning anything from inside the VM but I can use it resolves locally. Is there any DNS server issues on Azure you guys experience? It is the second time I am getting this and last time it fixed itself after 48 hours.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the DNS records of the webservice?  It will take time to replicate of course but its easy enough to check using nslookup in the VM and comparing to local.

Comment: No the webservice has remained unchanged. On the VM when I diagnose the network connection it comes up with: Your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource(DNS Server) is not responding

Comment: Do you have a custom network configured on the VM?  Can you browse to another resource in the browser, like www.bing.com?  You can look at IPConfig from the cmd line and see if you have DNS configured and if they are you could try to ping them.